# React Typescript With Bootstrap - Collapse Not Working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, bootstrap-5

I have a react typescript app with bootstrap 5. The app was created with `create-react-app` and bootstrap was installed with `npm i bootstrap`.

The app uses a button to toggle visibility of some content (straight copy from the first sample in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/collapse/).

This works fine until I try to invoke the bootstrap `Carouse.getOrCreateInstance()`. If that function is invoked, then the toggle stops, err, toggling.

If I comment out the `Carousel.getOrCreateInstance()` the collapse works fine. If I uncomment it, the component refuses to collapse - I have to ctrl-r refresh the page for it to collapse again.

Although the Carousel isn't used in this sample app, in my "real" app it is used and working fine (I use the Carousel instance to tell the carousel which of the images to display first). You will note also that the carousel div doesn't wrap or touch the component I want to collapse.

I should add that this uncollapsing behaviour occurs for all bootstrap collapsibles - navbars and accordions etc.

I'm using bootstrap 5.3.1, react 18.2.0 and node 18.17.1.

Here's the code:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'

import { Carousel } from 'bootstrap'

function App() {
  const ref = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!ref.current) {
      return
    }
    let carousel = Carousel.getOrCreateInstance(ref.current) // comment out this line and the collapse works
  }, [])
  return (
    <>
      <div id="imageCarousel" ref={ref} className="carousel slide">
      </div>
      <a className="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        Link with href
      </a>
      <button className="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        Button with data-bs-target
      </button>
      <div className="collapse" id="collapseExample">
        <div className="card card-body">
          Some placeholder content for the collapse component. This panel is hidden by default but revealed when the user activates the relevant trigger.
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I didn't need to use the Bootstrap Carousel API to control navigation to a specific image in the carousel image list.

I refactored my code to just toggle the 'active' class on the target `carousel-item` and that means I don't need to use the `Carousel.to()` API call.

And as mentioned in the original question, removing the `Carousel.to()` API call makes the problem go away.

I realise this may not make sense in the context of the original question, however in my complete app I needed to be able to click on an image thumbnail, which would BOTH open a modal containing a carousel AND then navigate to the clicked image inside that carousel.

The bootstrap doco says I can't control two bootstrap components with a single element (i.e. my thumbnail) data-bs-*:

> Be sure to only use one set of data attributes on a single element
> (e.g., you cannot trigger a tooltip and modal from the same button.)

My initial implementation used data-bs-* to control the modal, and  `Carousel.to()` API to control which carousel image to display. But that caused the weird non-collapse behaviour.

So I reworked the solution to control the modal with the image thumbnail button's data-bs-*, then add the 'active' class to the carousel item via the image thumbnail button's `onClick()` handler. Hence no need to call `Carouse.to(index)` and so no need to use the API at all.